# Codeigniter : How to insert last uri segment into database using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am creating a rating system in which when user rate any company then rate stored into rate along with the v_id table. (v_id is company id),

**This is my url in which i want to rate...**

- www.ABC.com/controller/function/company_id

Here company_id is getting from database. I want to store the company rating into  rate table. when user click on the star.

**Controller**

```
function visa_company_profile($v_id) {

        $data['total_ratings'] = $this->Visa_mdl->total_ratings($v_id); 
        $data['total_average'] = $this->Visa_mdl->total_average($v_id); 

        $result = $this->Visa_mdl->get_company_profile($v_id);
        $data['items_company_profile'] = $result;

        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('hotels/company_profile',$data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer');

    }
```

**Views**
This is ajax part in which i am sending the star values to the controller

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var click_val = 0;

$("#1_star").hover(function(){

    $("#1_star").attr("src","<?php echo base_url('assets/rating/star.png'); ?>");
    $("#2_star").attr("src","<?php echo base_url('assets/rating/blank_star.png'); ?>");
    $('#3_star').attr('src',"<?php echo base_url('assets/rating/blank_star.png'); ?>");
    $('#4_star').attr('src',"<?php echo base_url('assets/rating/blank_star.png'); ?>");
    $('#5_star').attr('src',"<?php echo base_url('assets/rating/blank_star.png'); ?>");
});

$("#1_star").click(function(){
    click_val = 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url('Account/loggedin');?>',
        success: function(logged_in) {
            if (logged_in === "1") {
                ajaxCall();

            }else {
                $("#l_modal").modal('show');
            }
        }
    });

});
function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        method : 'POST',
        data: {'click_val':click_val},
        url: '<?php echo base_url('Hotels/ratings/');?>',
        success: function() {
            location.reload();
        }
    });

}
```

**Star Controller To store Rate into data**
Here i am trying to get the company id from url and store  into column(v_id)  rate table.

```
function ratings() {
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
            $last = $this->uri->total_segments();
            $record_num = $this->uri->segment($last);
            $value = array (
                'rate' => $this->input->post('click_val'),
                'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'v_id' => $record_num
                );
            $this->Visa_mdl->ratings($value);
        }
```

**Model**

```
function ratings($value) {

            $this->db->insert('user_ratings',$value);
        }
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the above code?

Comment: v_id is storing 0 every time into rate table  @Shadow

Comment: Have you checked what's in the uri in the first place? I do not really see where `www.ABC.com/controller/function/company_id` url is sent to the server side as a parameter or target.

Comment: www.abc.com/Hotels/visa_company_profile/1 this is my url,

Comment: I am confused where should i put the uri segment because the inserting controller is different and the visa_company_profile is different controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it simply modifying you ajax function input value

```
function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        method : 'POST',
        data: {'click_val':click_val,'company_id':<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3)},
        url: '<?php echo base_url('Hotels/ratings/');?>',
        success: function() {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Again you can catch the company ID in your controller Function Hotels/ratings.

Answer (score 0):

```
function visa_company_profile($v_id) {

        $data['v_id'] = $v_id;
        $data['total_ratings'] = $this->Visa_mdl->total_ratings($v_id); 
        $data['total_average'] = $this->Visa_mdl->total_average($v_id); 

        $result = $this->Visa_mdl->get_company_profile($v_id);
        $data['items_company_profile'] = $result;

        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('hotels/company_profile',$data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer');

}
```

If you pass click value in url then ajax script should be like this:

```
function ajaxCall() {
    var company_id = '<?php echo $v_id; ?>';
    $.ajax({
        method : 'POST',
        data: {'click_val':click_val, 'company_id':company_id},
        url: '<?php echo base_url('Hotels/ratings/');?>'+click_val+'/'+company_id,
        success: function() {
            location.reload();
        }
    });

}
```

Because you are not passing click value in url so controller should be like that:

```
function ratings() {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $record_num = $this->input->post('company_id', true);
    $value = array (
        'rate' => $this->input->post('click_val', true),
        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'v_id' => $record_num
        );
    $this->Visa_mdl->ratings($value);
}
```

And controller:

```
function ratings($record_num = 0, $company_id = 0) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

    $value = array (
        'rate' => $record_num,
        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'v_id' => $company_id
        );
    $this->Visa_mdl->ratings($value);
}
```

Comment: `click_val` is not the company id, it is the number of starts and it is passed in the body of the request (post).

Comment: $record_num = $this->input->post('click_val', true);
'rate' => $this->input->post('click_val');

I am wondering how 1 variable "click_val" carry both company id and rating value. The answer is wrong.

Comment: @BikramPahi this was an example.

Comment: This is a good example how editing an answer can be misused - and still get it wrong. The original answer was plain wrong. The updated answer sort of works after the right answer was provided by someone else, but the descriptive text still only talks about the click value - which was not the question. However, the ajax code passes the click value and company id **twice**, once as a post parameter, and then encoded in the url. This answer does not provide an efficient solution to the problem and the descriptive parts are still wrong. Who on earth upvotes such an answer?

Comment: @Shadow because i have to show controller in both way. Think twice and see code.

Comment: No, you do not have to do that, see the accepted answer. There is no point of sending the same data twice.

Comment: @Shadow I wrote because I am giving answer for both in controller.

Comment: There was only one question. So, what both are you talking about?